# Добавить элемент в переменную

Tags: jquery

И так есть некое **n-е** количество блоков, есть **переменная**, которая должна содержать эти блоки. Первоначально все хорошо itemBlock = $('.filter_box .item_block'), но когда произвожу фильтрацию, мне нужно *обнулить переменную* и занести только те блоки *которые подходят условию*, условие написано корректно, а вот как добавить в переменную подходящие блоки, не знаю.

Comment: А что происходит с блоками, которые не подошли по фильтру? Вижу два варианта: добавлять подходящийм под фильтр блокам новый класс и получать список так:

   itemBlock = $('.filter_box .item_block.new_class');

или прятать неподходящие. В этом случае получение будет таким

   itemBlock = $('.filter_box .item_block:visible');

Comment: Ничего, у меня просто идет потом создание станиц, от количества выбранного (24,48,96 штук) и в ту функцию я просто передаю эту переменную. С классами можно, но хотелось бы без лишних манипуляций. По поводу второго способа, у меня часть (24,48,96 штук)видны, остальные нет, тоже лишние манипуляции)

Comment: ну тогда еще вариант:

    newItemBlocks = [];
    itemBlock.each(function () {
        if (/* проверка подходит ли блок $(this) по условие */) {
            newItemBlocks.push($(this));
        }
    });

Comment: Не такой массив формируется, нельзя использовать функции jquery (.hide(),.show()) для элементов

Comment: Возможно мы друг друга не поняли, но у элементов из масссива доступны все методы jQuery

http://jsfiddle.net/W2LMa/

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте о функции **[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**

Разметка:

```
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
```

---

JavaScript:

```
var item = $('.item'),
    # Фильтруем элементы по определенному признаку.  
    # Если функция вернет true, элемент останется в массиве.
    even = item.filter(function (el, i) {
        return $(i).index() % 2;
    }),
    # Можно фильтровать и на основе селектора.  
    # Тут наоборот, функция исключает элементы по селектору.
    css_even = item.filter(':odd');

# Выведет: 2, 4
even.each(function () {
    console.log('even: ' + $(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Ага, а если допустим нам нужно значение которое находиться в этом блок сравнить с переменной? И на основании этого фильтровать?

Comment: @denisneposeda, вы можете написать любую функцию для фильтрации.  
Еще раз подчеркну:  
1) В функцию последовательно передаются элементы.  
2) Вы по какому-то условию их сравниваете.
3) Хотите, чтобы элемент остался - возвращаете true. Нет - false.  
Просто, как 5 копеек.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, попробую, потом отпишусь

Comment: Все отлично, получилось.

Comment: @denisneposeda, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).